# find the average of columns for each row by ignoring strings in middle

Tags: r, dataframe, mean

Here is my data

```
para1  para2  c1   c2   c3   c4  c5   c6   
ast    abc    3    4    NR   6    8    6    
ast    pqr    4    8    2    5     3   2    
bc      sd  -0.3   2    0.4  NR    NR   3
```

I need output as

```
para1 para2  c1   c2   c3   c4  c5   c6   mean
    ast    abc   3   4    NR   6    8    6     20.8
    ast    pqr   4   8    2    5     3   2     4
    bc      sd -0.3  2    0.4  NR    NR   3    3
```

I want to find the mean of columns from column c2 to c6 for each row, by ignoring the String NR but it should consider the column count though NR is ignored.

Answer (score 1):

data:

```
df = read.table(text='para1  para2  c1   c2   c3   c4  c5   c6   
ast    abc    3    4    NR   6    8    6    
                ast    pqr    4    8    2    5     3   2    
                bc      sd  -0.3   2    0.4  NR    NR   3  ',header=T)
```

Note that the columns which have `NR` value in them are classed as `factor`, rather than `numeric`.

---

You could use `apply` for the row means:

```
apply(df[,c('c2','c3','c4','c5','c6')],1, function(x) 
                      {mean(as.numeric(as.character(x)),na.rm=T)})
```

Or alternatively convert to a matrix and use `rowMeans`:

```
x<-as.matrix(df[,c('c2','c3','c4','c5','c6')])
class(x)<-'numeric'
rowMeans(x,na.rm = T)
```

Output:

```
6.0 4.0 1.8
```

---

If you want to 'consider the count', if I understand you correctly, you should do:

```
apply(df[,c('c2','c3','c4','c5','c6')],1, function(x) 
                    {sum(as.numeric(as.character(x)),na.rm=T)/length(x)})
```

or

```
x<-as.matrix(df[,c('c2','c3','c4','c5','c6')])
class(x)<-'numeric'
x[is.na(x)]=0
rowMeans(x,na.rm = T)
```

Which returns:

```
4.80 4.00 1.08
```

Hope this helps!